# na values obtained from rsaga.get.modules

Tags: r, gis

I have installed SAGA GIS version 6.0.0 in my computer and I want to run modules from Rstudio. For that I have also downloaded RSAGA package. Firstly, I used rsaga.env () to select the path where SAGA GIS is found, then I tried to see libraries and modules availables with rsaga.get.libraries() and rsaga.get.modules(). Whilst rsaga.get.libraries returned a list of availables libraries, rsaga.get.modules only gave NA values. In addition rsaga.geoprocessor and rsaga.get.usage produced errors.

```
library(RSAGA)

env <- rsaga.env(path= "C:/Program Files (x86)/SAGA-GIS", 
                 modules="C:/Program Files (x86)/SAGA-GIS/tools")

rsaga.get.libraries(path=env$modules)

rsaga.get.modules("climate_tools", env=env)
```

---

```
$climate_tools
   code name interactive
1    NA <NA>       FALSE
2    NA <NA>       FALSE
3    NA <NA>       FALSE
4    NA <NA>       FALSE
5    NA <NA>       FALSE
6    NA <NA>       FALSE
7    NA <NA>       FALSE
8    NA <NA>       FALSE
9    NA <NA>       FALSE
10   NA <NA>       FALSE
11   NA <NA>       FALSE
12   NA <NA>       FALSE
13   NA <NA>       FALSE
14   NA <NA>       FALSE
15   NA <NA>       FALSE
16   NA <NA>       FALSE
17   NA <NA>       FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

SAGA GIS version 6.0 is currently not supported by RSAGA 0.94-6, which is available on CRAN. You have to use a new version of RSAGA, which supports SAGA GIS up to version 6.1. You can get it from https://github.com/be-marc/RSAGA.